# Missing required param: card

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

In setting up so users can create a new card on file for Stripe I am getting a `Stripe::InvalidRequestError at /subscriptions/changecard`. The error message is `Missing required param: card` and points to the line `@customer.cards.create({:card => @user.subscription.stripe_card_token})`

If the user has a subscription they should be able to visit /subscriptions/changecard and fill out the form which will add a new card.

Subscriptions controller:

```
  def new
    plan = Plan.find(params[:plan_id])
    @subscription = plan.subscriptions.build
    if params[:PayerID]
      @subscription.paypal_customer_token = params[:PayerID]
      @subscription.paypal_payment_token = params[:token]
      @subscription.email = @subscription.paypal.checkout_details.email
    end
  end

  def create
    @subscription = Subscription.new(params[:subscription])
    if @subscription.save_with_payment
      redirect_to @subscription, :notice => "Thank you for subscribing!"
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def show
    @subscription = Subscription.find(params[:id])
  end

  def paypal_checkout
    plan = Plan.find(params[:plan_id])
    subscription = plan.subscriptions.build
    redirect_to subscription.paypal.checkout_url(
      return_url: new_subscription_url(:plan_id => plan.id),
      cancel_url: root_url
    )
  end

    def updatesubscription
      @user = current_user
      @customer = Stripe::Customer.retrieve(@user.subscription.stripe_customer_token)
      @customer.update_subscription(:plan => "1", :prorate => true)
     current_user.save!
      flash.alert = 'Your subscription has been updated!'
      redirect_to root_url
     end

     def cancelsubscription
       @user = current_user
         @customer = Stripe::Customer.retrieve(@user.subscription.stripe_customer_token)
         @customer.cancel_subscription()
         current_user.save!
         flash.alert = 'Your subscription has been cancelled successfully!'
         redirect_to root_url
       end

       def showcard
         @user = current_user
         Stripe::Customer.retrieve(@user.subscription.stripe_customer_token).cards.all()
       end

        def changecard
       @user = current_user       
       @customer = Stripe::Customer.retrieve(@user.subscription.stripe_customer_token)

         card = @customer.cards.create({
           :card => @user.subscription.stripe_customer_token
         })

         @customer.default_card = card
         @customer.save
       end
end
```

View:

```
Add new Credit Card
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
  <% if @subscription.errors.any? %>
    <div class="error_messages">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@subscription.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this subscription from being saved:</h2>
      <ul>
      <% @subscription.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.hidden_field :plan_id %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :stripe_card_token %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= radio_button_tag :pay_with, :card, true %>
    <%= label_tag :pay_with_card do %>
      <%= image_tag "visa.png" %>
      <%= image_tag "mastercard.png" %>
      <%= image_tag "discover.png" %>
      <%= image_tag "american_express.png" %>
      <%= image_tag "jcb.png" %>
  </div>
  <% end %>

  <div id="billing_fields">
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user.id %> 
      <%= f.label :email %>
      <%= f.text_field :email %>
    </div>
    <% if @subscription.payment_provided? %>
      Payment has been provided. Click "Subscribe" to complete the subscription.
    <% else %>
      <div class="field">
        <%= label_tag :card_number, "Credit Card Number" %>
        <%= text_field_tag :card_number, nil, name: nil %>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <%= label_tag :card_code, "Security Code on Card (CVV)" %>
        <%= text_field_tag :card_code, nil, name: nil %>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <%= label_tag :card_month, "Card Expiration" %>
        <%= select_month nil, {add_month_numbers: true}, {name: nil, id: "card_month"} %>
        <%= select_year nil, {start_year: Date.today.year, end_year: Date.today.year+15}, {name: nil, id: "card_year"} %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
    <div id="stripe_error">
      <noscript>JavaScript is not enabled and is required for this form. First enable it in your web browser settings.</noscript>
    </div>
    <div class="actions">
      <%= f.submit "New Card" %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Routes:

```
  get "subscriptions/cancelsubscription"
  get "subscriptions/updatesubscription"
  get "subscriptions/changecard"


  resources :charges
  resources :subscriptions
  resources :plans
  get 'paypal/checkout', to: 'subscriptions#paypal_checkout'
```

Comment: A `Stripe::InvalidRequestError` can be thrown if an invalid token is passed to the `card` key. Can you verify that `@user.subscription.stripe_card_token` is outputting a valid value?

Comment: @zeantsoi I believe you are right and card_token does not exist. The API says to use `customer.cards.create({:card => TOKEN_ID})` so that's how I came up with the line. I'm not sure what I should do as in my database I only have `stripe_customer_token` which equals the customer_id.

Comment: It seems like you're going about updating the card the wrong way. The documentation states: [_Creating a new credit card will not change the customer's existing default credit card; you should update the customer with a new default_card for that. If the customer has no default credit card, the added credit card will become the default._](https://stripe.com/docs/api/ruby#card_object)

Comment: I can do that with `@customer.default_card = card`. When I change the original code to make default card I get a Invalid token id for  `card = @customer.cards.create`. I updated the code to show the latest. With the new code the new card gets saved as default, but the user will have multiple cards on file. Unless perhaps the best method would be to just have the user delete their card on file, and then add a new one. I will have to brainstorm to see how I should go about that without it deleting the subscription.